# Ramdisk / tmpfs which does not remove subfolders and symbolic links on reboot

Tags: fstab, symbolic-link, tmpfs

I created a temporary harddrive which uses the system memory (ramdisk) with these commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/ramdisk
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2048M tmpfs /media/ramdisk
```

After that i created a subfolder (stream) on the ramdisk

I managed to keep the ramdisk on reboot by adding this line:

```
grep /media/ramdisk /etc/mtab | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

And i created a symbolic link from my /home/ubuntumaster/stream folder to my /media/ramdisk/stream folder with the following command:

```
ln -s /media/ramdisk/stream /home/ubuntumaster/streamer/stream
```

But when rebooting the symbolic link and the subfolder in the ramdisk is being removed. How can I make this symbolic link permanent? Same is for the subfolder on the ramdisk.

Otherwise I will have to create the subfolder on the ramdisk and the symbolic link on every reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reboot is not required to empty out a `tmpfs` mount. If you `mount` a `tmpfs` mount, then populate it (for example, create a subdirectory underneath the mount), then `umount` it, your subdirectory is gone (if you redo the mount, it starts out empty). If you want persistence across mounts (let alone reboots), `tmpfs` by itself will not suffice.

One way to use `tmpfs` in such a way that the mount is initially nonempty is to use [OverlayFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS), with a nonempty lower directory, and a `tmpfs` mount as the upper directory.

Your question says that the symlink disappears as a result of the reboot, but I don't believe that's what happens. The symlink, in a persistent directory, points at a (possibly non-existent) directory in the `tmpfs` mount.

A simpler approach which might suit your purposes is to replace the symlink with a `tmpfs` mount point,  using something like this:

```
rm /home/ubuntumaster/streamer/stream
mkdir /home/ubuntumaster/streamer/stream
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2048M tmpfs /home/ubuntumaster/streamer/stream
```

If you choose to use `/home/ubuntumaster/streamer/stream` as a mount point rather than a symlink, the `/etc/fstab` for that might look like this:

```
tmpfs /home/ubuntumaster/streamer/stream tmpfs rw,size=2048M 0 0
```

If you prefer to use a symlink, the target of the symlink can be the `tmpfs` mount point; that might look something like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/stream
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2048M tmpfs /media/stream
ln -s /media/stream /home/ubuntumaster/streamer/stream
```

You can avoid problems during reboot by testing changes to `/etc/fstab` using the mount command before you reboot. In the case where `/home/ubuntumaster/streamer/stream` is not a symlink, that might be this (after editing `/etc/fstab`):

```
sudo mount /home/ubuntumaster/streamer/stream
```

If, say, you mistakenly skip the `mkdir`, `mount` will complain about the missing mount point.

Comment: Aah that is even better! What if I replace the line in fstab with thid one will the stream folder be like you describe on the next reboot?

Comment: Yes, I believe that line in fstab should have the intended effect. You can try it without a reboot if you `sudo mount /home/ubuntumaster/streamer/stream`; you can then try `df /home/ubuntumaster/streamer/stream` to confirm it's a mount point.

Comment: Great I edited fstab to that line you gave now the pc wont boot anymore...

Comment: I think the reason for it not to boot is because the stream folder does not exist. I will have to create it first then mount it in fstab.

Comment: Sorry about the inconvenience. I edited my answer to be more specific about how to set up the `tmpfs` mount point.

Comment: Added the directory and it works fine now thanks man!

Comment: Is there a way to have TMPFS dump itself to disk and reload on reboot?